# I have a requirement in powerapps to collect all days in a month based on year and specific month

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-modeldriven, powerapps-collection

I have a requirement in powerapps to collect all days in a month based on year and specific month

and i tried below formula

**ClearCollect(
DayCollection,
DateAdd(Date(2024,2,1),Sequence(DateDiff((Date(2024,2,1)),DateAdd((Date(2024,2,1)),1,TimeUnit.Months)),0,1))
)**

Here 2024 is year and 2 is month

but my collection is getting like junk values (attached in image).

how to format this to dd/mm/yyyy fromat?

how to format this junk values to dd/mm/yyyy fromat?

Comment: Your expression looks valid; what are the "junk values" that you are getting (you probably forgot to attach the image).